# ARBodyTracking in iOS13: how to get real world coordinates of body joints?

Tags: swift, arkit, motion-detection

I have an app that uses iOS 13 body tracking to place some markers in a human body in real time using ARKit.

[image: See attached picture where white markers are placed in the lower body].

The following code allows me to draw the markers in real time and to get their coordinates in the screen.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {


    if let detectedBody = frame.detectedBody {

        guard let interfaceOrientation = arView.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation else { return }
        let transform = frame.displayTransform(for: interfaceOrientation, viewportSize: arView.frame.size)

       //This array contains only the lower body joints
             var arrayOfJoints = [detectedBody.skeleton.jointLandmarks[8],detectedBody.skeleton.jointLandmarks[9],detectedBody.skeleton.jointLandmarks[10],detectedBody.skeleton.jointLandmarks[11],detectedBody.skeleton.jointLandmarks[12],detectedBody.skeleton.jointLandmarks[13],detectedBody.skeleton.jointLandmarks[16]]



        //Todo lo de este for estaba en el .forEach
        for i in 0...arrayOfJoints.count - 1 {

            let normalizedCenter = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arrayOfJoints[i][0]), y: CGFloat(arrayOfJoints[i][1])).applying(transform)
            let center = normalizedCenter.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: arView.frame.width, y: arView.frame.height))

            let circleWidth: CGFloat = 10
            let circleHeight: CGFloat = 10
            let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: center.x - circleWidth/2, y: center.y - circleHeight/2), size: CGSize(width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
            let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()


            circleLayer.fillColor = .init(srgbRed: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)


            circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

            arView.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)


        }

    }

}
```

However, I can't find a way to obtain the real world coordinates to see, for example, what is the hip displacement in cm during the squat. Is it even possible to translate those points to real world coordinates using ARKit?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access 3D joints positions by using ARBodyAnchor. Use didUpdate anchor function from `ARSessionDelegate`:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {
        guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor else { continue }
        // Accessing joints transform
    }
}
```

You can get either model Transform which will return transform in relation to `root` anchor. For an example for left foot transform:

```
let leftFootModelTransform = bodyAnchor.skeleton.modelTransform(for: "left_foot_joint")
```

or you can access local transform which is in relation to `parent` joint. In case of foot, parent will be knee joint `"left_leg_joint"` :

```
let leftFootLocalTransform = bodyAnchor.skeleton.localTransform(for: "left_foot_joint")
```

You can find out more from WWDC video Bringing people into AR:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/607/